# elegant list manipulation in python

Tags: python, list

In python, What is the most preferred (pythonic) way to do the following:

> You are given a list. If the list is not empty, all items in the list are guaranteed to be strings. Each item in the list is either the empty string, or is guaranteed to return `True` if `isdigit()` is called on the item.

Starting with such a list, what is the most elegant way to end up with a list such that it has all items from the original list, except for the empty strings?

Comment: I guess whatever I've tried is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It could have been relevant. And it's good to show you made an effort to try it first.

Comment: You say it could have been relevant but you don't say how. So let me ask this - just how exactly could it have been relevant? And why would you assume the answer depends on what efforts I have made first?

Comment: The answer doesn't depend on what you have tried, but it often makes your question clearer, shows that you made an effort to work it out yourself, and in general helps the question be a better one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `filter()` with the default identity function (`None`):

```
newlist = filter(None, origlist)
```

alternatively, a list comprehension:

```
newlist = [el for el in origlist if el]
```

Comment: Thanks, but which one would you choose?

Comment: @chefsmart: Python 2: `filter()`. Python 3: `filter()` or list comprehension, depending on wether an iterator will do or if I *have* to have a list.

Comment: @chefsmart I'd say this is a controversial decision though most people would vouch for the second one because they think `filter` is not as clear. I like the first. It can also be written as `filter(bool, origlist)`

Comment: @jamylak: Indeed; and the C code treats `None` and `bool` exactly the same way, with a *fast* direct call to `PyObject_IsTrue`.